# Using rvest to run a list of character values plugged into a URL

Tags: r, rvest

Okay, so I am retrieving some data from a website using a script like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

patriot_url <- "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/%s"
team_list <- c("american", "bucknell", "colgate", "navy", "lehigh", "army", "lafayette", "boston-university", "loyola-md", "holy-cross")

patriot <- 
  for(team in team_list) {
patriot_url <- sprintf(patriot_url, team)
patriot_values <- read_html(patriot_url) %>%
  html_nodes("td[data-stat]") %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  str_trim %>%
  matrix(ncol = 17, byrow = T) %>% 
  as.data.frame
  Sys.sleep(1) }
```

So it's taking that URL and then attaching the name from `team_list` and feeding it into a `read_html` where it then retrieves certain data.

How do I get it to loop so that it does all ten characters and the subsuquent data from the URL so that the final output/data frame is a combination of all ten results?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for.  The data.frame requires some cleaning.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

patriot_url <- "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/%s"
team_list <- c("american", "bucknell", "colgate", "navy", "lehigh", "army", "lafayette", "boston-university", "loyola-md", "holy-cross")

patriot <- data.frame() 
for(team in team_list) {
    patriot_url <- sprintf(patriot_url, team)
    patriot_values <- html_table(read_html(patriot_url))[[1]] 
    patriot <- rbind(patriot, patriot_values)
    Sys.sleep(1)
}
```